# На некоторых устройствах не отображается progressBar

Tags: java, android

Ситуация следующая есть activity  в ней есть progressBar ( он постоянно вращается) . Беда в чем , на некоторых устройствах  progressBar просто белый лист . Таких как Prestigio Muze D3 PSP 3530 DUO или Samsung SM-J120H Galaxy J1  таких устройств крайне мало но они есть . На остальных же устройствах все хорошо работает - все отображается . Я предположил , что возможно это версия Android так как у ник одинаковые версии а именно android 5.0.2 но нет на эмуляторе с  таким же андроидом все отображается не могу предположить , что это может быть .
Любые идеи буду рад спасибо....

Да и еще я заметил , что у выше приведенных устройств (одинаковый графический процессор) Mali-400MP2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@color/Dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="@string/database_update" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

///

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

//

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего дело в последних 2 атрибутах и/или стиле. Попробуйте иначе сделать разметку, если причина в первом варианте. Т.е. оберните прогресс во фрейм, например. Фрейму высоту в 0 выставить, вес в 1. Прогрессу же - матчпарент для обоих параметров. Если это не поможет - попробуйте стиль сменить. Вдруг производители девайсов его поменяли, вот он и глючит. Ну или это косяк Гугла в конкретной версии ОС.

Answer (score 0):

Из-за кастомизаций системы разными производителями и просто из-за багов в ОС у вас могут возникнуть проблемы, если вы ссылаетесь на системные атрибуты `?android:attr`. Уберите этот стиль и задайте стиль сами, чтобы он лежал в вашем проекте.

Кроме этого, у @Rhisiart [в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28674548) была аналогичная проблема с отображением прогресс бара на Android 5.0.2. Он предлагает воркэраунд в виде переопределения проблемных стилей:

```xml
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Build LRX22G (5.0.2 Nexus 7) fails to display progress bar so we'll use Holo instead of Material -->
    <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28674548 -->
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar</item>
</style>
```

Вам следует поискать устройство с Android 5.0.2, чтобы не фиксить баги вслепую.